# Spyder IDE for python not recognizing path to packages

Tags: python, package, anaconda, spyder

I am having a weird issue where running code from Spyder works for majority of my code but I installed a new package (Basemap) and I get the following error:

```
runfile('H:/Python_Programs/mapping.py', wdir='H:/Python_Programs')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-19-5b87e60107c2>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('H:/Python_Programs/mapping.py', wdir='H:/Python_Programs')

  File "C:\Users\Charanjit\AppData\Local\Continuum\AnacondaNew\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Charanjit\AppData\Local\Continuum\AnacondaNew\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 74, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "H:/Python_Programs/mapping.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

ImportError: No module named basemap
```

I installed Basemap 1.0.7 version using conda to the only environment i have created but Spyder does not recognize it at all.

Any help would be appreciated here.

Answer (score 0):

Spyder will be using Python.exe in your Anaconda folder (default install location C:\Anaconda) and you need to use that Python version to install any new modules. You likely used a different version. Also note that after installing the module you need to close and restart Spyder.